# Script not running thru all iterations, and getting stuck in a loop

Tags: loops, google-apps-script

I have a script that is working.  It is to loop thru a number of different spreadsheets, and make the same edits in each.  The edits are:  Adding 2 formulas, conditional formatting a cell, and removing protection from 6 sheets.  But there seems to be an issue with the first 'FOR' loop.  It is only doing 2 iterations, then keeps running. I have had to force stop each of my attempts after several minutes.  I am fairly new, so I think the issue may be with my syntax and brackets {}.

```
  var sheetIds = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Blueprints");       //Change as needed  -DONE
  var values = sheetIds.getRange('j19:j96').getValues();                                  //Change to proper range -DONE    j3:j96
  var idList = values.map(function (row) {
    return row[0];
  }).filter(function (id) {
    return id;
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {  

   // var form1 = "Roster!A1"
   // var form2 = "KPI!A1"

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idList[i]);
    var ss = s.getSheetByName('Blueprint');
    var roster = ss.getRange('e3');
    var kpi = ss.getRange('f3');

    var form1 = "Roster!A1"
    var form2 = "KPI!A1"

    roster.setFormula(form1)
    kpi.setFormula(form2)

    //var range = ss.getRange('t1')
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenTextContains('Advocates')
      .setFontColor('#c9daf8')
      .setRanges([roster])
      .build();
   var rules = ss.getConditionalFormatRules();
    rules.push(rule);
    ss.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);

  //var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var store = s.getSheetByName('Store');
  var prot = store.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)
  for (var i = 0; i < prot.length; i++) {
  var protection = prot[i];
  if (protection.canEdit()) {
    protection.remove();
           }
       }
  var adv1 = s.getSheetByName('Advocate1');
  var prot1 = adv1.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)
  for (var i = 0; i < prot1.length; i++) {
  var protection1 = prot1[i];
  if (protection1.canEdit()) {
    protection1.remove();
           }
       }
  var adv2 = s.getSheetByName('Advocate2');
  var prot2 = adv2.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)
  for (var i = 0; i < prot2.length; i++) {
  var protection2 = prot2[i];
  if (protection2.canEdit()) {
    protection2.remove();
          } 
       }
  var adv3 = s.getSheetByName('Advocate3');
  var prot3 = adv3.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)
  for (var i = 0; i < prot3.length; i++) {
  var protection3 = prot3[i];
  if (protection3.canEdit()) {
    protection3.remove();
           }
      }
  var adv4 = s.getSheetByName('Advocate4');
  var prot4 = adv4.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)
  for (var i = 0; i < prot4.length; i++) {
  var protection4 = prot4[i];
  if (protection4.canEdit()) {
    protection4.remove();
           }
       }
  var adv5 = s.getSheetByName('Advocate5');
  var prot5 = adv5.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)
  for (var i = 0; i < prot5.length; i++) {
  var protection5 = prot5[i];
  if (protection5.canEdit()) {
    protection5.remove();  
          }

       }
    }
}
```

It would be a massive time saver if I could figure this out!!!

Comment: You are using the same index in all of your inner loops and your outer loop.  Change your inner indices.  They can all be the same if you wish as long as they don't over lap each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

I just replaced all of the inner loop indices with j

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheetIds=SpreadsheetApp.getActive.getSheetByName("Blueprints");       
  var values=sheetIds.getRange('j19:j96').getValues();                                  
  var idList=values.map(function (row) {return row[0];}).filter(function (id) {return id;});
  for (var i=0;i<idList.length;i++) {  
    var s=SpreadsheetApp.openById(idList[i]);
    var ss=s.getSheetByName('Blueprint');
    var roster=ss.getRange('e3');
    var kpi=ss.getRange('f3');
    var form1="Roster!A1";
    var form2="KPI!A1";
    roster.setFormula(form1);
    kpi.setFormula(form2);
    var rule=SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule().whenTextContains('Advocates').setFontColor('#c9daf8').setRanges([roster]).build();
    var rules=ss.getConditionalFormatRules();
    rules.push(rule);
    ss.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
    var store=s.getSheetByName('Store');
    var prot=store.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)
    for(var j=0;j<prot.length; j++) {
      var protection=prot[j];
      if (protection.canEdit()) {
        protection.remove();
      }
    }
    var adv1=s.getSheetByName('Advocate1');
    var prot1=adv1.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)
    for (var j=0; j < prot1.length; j++) {
      var protection1=prot1[j];
      if (protection1.canEdit()) {
        protection1.remove();
      }
    }
    var adv2=s.getSheetByName('Advocate2');
    var prot2=adv2.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)
    for (var j=0; j < prot2.length; j++) {
      var protection2=prot2[j];
      if (protection2.canEdit()) {
        protection2.remove();
      } 
    }
    var adv3=s.getSheetByName('Advocate3');
    var prot3=adv3.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)
    for (var j=0; j < prot3.length; j++) {
      var protection3=prot3[j];
      if (protection3.canEdit()) {
        protection3.remove();
      }
    }
    var adv4=s.getSheetByName('Advocate4');
    var prot4=adv4.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)
    for (var j=0; j < prot4.length; j++) {
      var protection4=prot4[j];
      if (protection4.canEdit()) {
        protection4.remove();
      }
    }
    var adv5=s.getSheetByName('Advocate5');
    var prot5=adv5.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)
    for (var j=0; j < prot5.length; j++) {
      var protection5=prot5[j];
      if (protection5.canEdit()) {
        protection5.remove();  
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That seems to have worked!!!  Had to make a minor edit of splitting the sheetIDs variable into the spreadsheet, then sheet.  Cooper to the rescue again!!!